# how to delete a worksheet from a workbook in Node.js? // TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, worksheet-function, worksheet, sheetjs

I need to delete a worksheet from a workbook of an Excel in Node.js. I use the SheetJs (I would preferable need an answer using this one, but I highly appreciate all of the other possibilities, I can change). Having searching for days, but could not find the solution.

So I have this (if you need code for test):

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');
workBook = xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx", {cellDates:true});
const headerData = ["Id", "Name", "Description", "Due Date", "Priority", "Status", "Notes"];
const workSheet = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet([headerData]);
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, workSheet,"TO-DEL");
```

and I tried this but it does not work:

```
workSheet.delete();
```

or this...

```
workBook.Sheets["TO-DEL"].delete();
```

this is how it ends:

```
xlsx.writeFile(workBook, 'todo-list.xlsx');
```

The error is:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'delete' of undefined**

Do you have any idea or experience with this so you can help me please? Highly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works perfect:

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');

const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
workbook.xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx").then(function() {
        const worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
        console.log(worksheet);
        workbook.removeWorksheet(worksheet.id);
        return workbook.xlsx.writeFile( "todo-list.xlsx");
});
```